# Scaling relationships for home ranges based on linear models

Tags: self-learning, regression, biology

I'm reading through a [paper](http://www.dulvy.com/uploads/2/1/0/4/21048414/tamburello_2015_amnat.pdf) that describes the home range variation across various groups of animals. The authors calculate some parameters for a linear model for these groups. I'm having trouble getting the answers they provide as the output.

For example, their model for birds gives as regression coefficients:

$log_{10}(a)=2.79$ and $b = 1.50$

Their full linear model is:

$log{10}(HRA_{1kg}) = log{10}(a) + b * log{10}(M)$

where $HRA_{1kg}$ is the predicted home-range size (in m^2) at M = 1kg.

From this they get the value of 49,421,691 m^2 but I don't see how they get there. For instance, log10 of 1 should equal zero leaving the answer equal to the intercept.

Hope you can help.

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to put $M=1$ into the equation. For $\log_{10}{M}\approx{3.2692}$ it works ...

Comment: But they say in their paper "predicted home-range size (in m^2) at M = 1 kg"

Comment: Yes, that's the definition of $HRA_{\text{1 kg}}$ but I believe it has nothing to do with the other variable in the equation, $M$. I know it's confusing, I think so too. But plugging in $M=1$ doesn't result in the value that they told, and I'm also trying to understand the logic behind this.